# Has_many through with multiple relationships between the entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these model definitions:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :users_favourites_properties, class_name: 'UsersFavouritesProperties', dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => :property_id
  has_many :favourites, :class_name => "User", through: :users_favourites_properties

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :properties

  has_many :users_favourites_properties, class_name: 'UsersFavouritesProperties', dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :favourites, class_name: "Property", through: :users_favourites_properties

end

class UsersFavouritesProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "favourites"

  belongs_to :favourites, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id, :primary_key => :id
  belongs_to :favourites, class_name: 'Property', :foreign_key => :property_id, :primary_key => :id, counter_cache: :users_count
end
```

When I execute:

```
current_user.favourites << property
```

The UsersFavouritesProperties object created has the same user_id and property_id because the user_id is beign setted with the property_id.

Do you know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what the **association name** is for.

Each association method call (like `has_many`) adds certain methods to a model that allow for easy lookup for associated objects.

The **name of association** means (in scope of a model) **"what is it for me"**. A symbol you specify first is an association name, and it is used (among other things) as a name of a method that **you** will use to access that association.

By defining an association named `favourites` once, you've defined the methods for `UsersFavouritesProperties`. The second time you define an association with the same name, some of the first one is **redefined** and crazy things can happen.

So, following that **"what is it for me"** principle, you can figure that a `User` associated with a certain `UsersFavouritesProperty` is `UsersFavouritesProperty`'s `user`, and the resulting association, that you have:

```
belongs_to :favourites, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id, :primary_key => :id
```

should be more like simple:

```
belongs_to :user
```

The rest is not even needed, as it follows the Rails' convention: class name and foreign key can be derived from association name in standard ways (capitalize for class name, add `_id` for foreign key), primary key is default.

I strongly recommend you read the [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) and [let ActiveRecord guess the most](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#keep-ar-defaults) you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
belongs_to :favourites, ...
belongs_to :favourites, ...
```

Should be

```
belongs_to :user, ...
belongs_to :property, ...
```

You can't use two keys for `belongs_to`